# Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID when signup

Tags: swift, xcode, keychain, autofill

I have an issue with my sign up page when I try to sign up a new user. I changed the username and password content type to the following:

```
passwordTextField.textContentType = .newPassword
passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
emailTextField.textContentType = .username
emailTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

I setup association between website and application successfully and it is working fine. Saving password in iCloud keychain is also working fine but when I try to implement Automatic Strong Passwords suggestion I get this error.

also on the keychain sharing.

### [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.example.com due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled ##

I knew error is self explanatory but in [WWDC 2018 session 204](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204) they didn't tell anything about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic Strong Passwords suggestion works if user has enabled the iCloud keychain in its iPhone. I resolved this error by doing the following steps

How to enable iCloud keychain

1. Go to the Setting
2. Tap on UserName (Apple Id)
3. Tap on iCloud
4. Tap on keychain
5. Enable iCLoud Keychain